# What unit of time does the delay refer to?

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

In the tracer(x,y) function of python's standard turtle graphics where x is said to be the number of updates and y is said to be the delay time and calling the tracer does turn of the tracing animation. For example, in the call of turtle.tracer(1, 50), what unit of time does the delay of 50 refer to?

Comment: Should be fairly easy to find in the documentation itself. Did you look through it?
If yes, tell us what specifically you could not understand in the documentation.

Comment: I've answered anyways. https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.delay

Comment: It appears to be with some difference to how turtle.delay works which is exactly in milliseconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs:

> Set or return the drawing delay in milliseconds. (This is
>   approximately the time interval between two consecutive canvas
>   updates.) The longer the drawing delay, the slower the animation.

Comment: how can we interpret it with the update argument does the speed become twice as fast?